Do we need to create a new Preferences DataStore each time when perform DataStore-to-DataStore migrations on Android?
I have a v1datastore. & I made some change & migrate it to v2datastore as shown below.
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("V1PreferencesDataStore")
    fun provideV1PreferencesDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext appContext: Context,
        coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    ): DataStore<Preferences> {
        val dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler {
                emptyPreferences()
            },
            scope = coroutineScope,
            produceFile = {
                appContext.dataStoreFile(V1_DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME)
            },
            migrations = listOf()
        )
        return dataStore
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("v2PreferencesDataStore")
    fun provideV2PreferencesDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext appContext: Context,
        @Named("PreferencesDataStore") oldPreferencesDataStore: DataStore<Preferences>,
        coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    ): DataStore<Preferences> {

        val dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler {
                emptyPreferences()
            },
            scope = coroutineScope,
            produceFile = {
                appContext.dataStoreFile(V2_DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME)
            }, migrations = listOf(object : DataMigration<Preferences> {

                // Specify your condition for whether the migration should happen
                override suspend fun shouldMigrate(currentData: Preferences): Boolean {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).d("shouldMigrate currentData: $currentData")
                    return !(currentData[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV1ToV2DataStoreMigration] ?: false)
                }

                // Instruction on how exactly the old data is transformed into new data
                override suspend fun migrate(currentData: Preferences): Preferences {
                    val oldData = oldPreferencesDataStore.data.first().asMap()
                    val currentMutablePrefs = currentData.toMutablePreferences()

                    mapOldToV1Prefs(oldData, currentMutablePrefs)

                    // Mark migration as complete
                    currentMutablePrefs[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV1ToV2DataStoreMigration] = true
                    return currentMutablePrefs.toPreferences()
                }

                // Once the migration is over, clean up the old storage
                override suspend fun cleanUp() {
                    oldPreferencesDataStore.deleteSession()
                }
            })
        )
        return dataStore
    }
}

Then further I made changes & need to migrate it to v3datastore. Do I need to create each time newPreferencesDataStore? I know migrations parameter can take list of DataMigration but where I will get (latest old datastore) v2datastore instance while creating v2datastore.
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("v2PreferencesDataStore")
fun provideV2PreferencesDataStore(
    @ApplicationContext appContext: Context,
    @Named("PreferencesDataStore") oldPreferencesDataStore: DataStore<Preferences>,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
): DataStore<Preferences> {

    val dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler {
            emptyPreferences()
        },
        scope = coroutineScope,
        produceFile = {
            appContext.dataStoreFile(V2_DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME)
        }, migrations = listOf(
            // v1 to v2 migration
            object : DataMigration<Preferences> {

            // Specify your condition for whether the migration should happen
            override suspend fun shouldMigrate(currentData: Preferences): Boolean {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("shouldMigrate currentData: $currentData")
                return !(currentData[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV1ToV2DataStoreMigration] ?: false)
            }

            // Instruction on how exactly the old data is transformed into new data
            override suspend fun migrate(currentData: Preferences): Preferences {
                val oldData = oldPreferencesDataStore.data.first().asMap()
                val currentMutablePrefs = currentData.toMutablePreferences()

                mapOldToV1Prefs(oldData, currentMutablePrefs)

                // Mark migration as complete
                currentMutablePrefs[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV1ToV2DataStoreMigration] = true
                return currentMutablePrefs.toPreferences()
            }

            // Once the migration is over, clean up the old storage
            override suspend fun cleanUp() {
                oldPreferencesDataStore.deleteSession()
            }
        },
            // v2 to v3 migration
            object : DataMigration<Preferences> {

            // Specify your condition for whether the migration should happen
            override suspend fun shouldMigrate(currentData: Preferences): Boolean {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d("shouldMigrate currentData: $currentData")
                return !(currentData[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV2ToV3DataStoreMigration] ?: false)
            }

            // Instruction on how exactly the old data is transformed into new data
            override suspend fun migrate(currentData: Preferences): Preferences {
                // I CANNOT GET V2 DATASTORE HERE
                val oldData = oldPreferencesDataStore.data.first().asMap()
                val currentMutablePrefs = currentData.toMutablePreferences()

                mapV2ToV3Prefs(oldData, currentMutablePrefs)

                // Mark migration as complete
                currentMutablePrefs[PreferencesKeys.hasDoneV2ToV3DataStoreMigration] = true
                return currentMutablePrefs.toPreferences()
            }

            // Once the migration is over, clean up the old storage
            override suspend fun cleanUp() {
                oldPreferencesDataStore.deleteSession()
            }
        })
    )
    return dataStore
}


// I CANNOT GET V2 DATASTORE HERE


val oldData = oldPreferencesDataStore.data.first().asMap()

